Type hinting a function returning a instance of a class whose attribute's type varies
I am using dataclasses in a Python 3.11 project as a thin return type around a status code and a  response of some operation (each is represented by a particular function), and optionally an id of the data referenced in a database. I do this to standardize the return type.
I like the interface of the dataclass better than namedtuples and namedtuples better than tuples.
The status code is always an int, whereas the response depends on the operation type and result.
An operation may be successful, in which case I need to return the data, which may be an array or a map, or it may fail, in which case I would like to return the reason for the failure.
Here's my implementation:
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any, List, Dict


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class OperationResult:
    status_code: int
    response: str | List | Dict
    id: int | None = None

The fact that the response can have multiple types is not great, which shows up immediately as a type hinting problem.
Here's an example to help explain:
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List, Dict


@dataclass(
    frozen=True,
)
class OperationResult:
    status_code: int
    response: str | List | Dict
    id: int | None = None


def operation1(a, b) -> OperationResult:
    # Do stuff

    try:
        res = a / b
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return OperationResult(500, "Failed")
    else:
        return OperationResult(200, {"response": res})


def operation2(a, b) -> OperationResult:
    # Do stuff

    try:
        res = a / b
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return OperationResult(500, "Failed")
    else:
        return OperationResult(200, [res])


result1 = operation1(1, 2)

if result1.status_code == 200:
    print(result1.response["response"])

result2 = operation2(1, 2)

if result2.status_code == 200:
    print(result2.response["response"])

If I run mypy on this module, I get two errors:
error: Invalid index type "str" for "str | list[Any] | dict[Any, Any]"; expected type "SupportsIndex | slice"  [index]
but if I change it to:
result1 = operation1(1, 2)

if result1.status_code == 200:
    print(result1.response[0])

result2 = operation2(1, 2)

if result2.status_code == 200:
    print(result2.response[0])

mypy is happy.
In the end, is there a way I can inform mypy or other type checkers that the return type is wrapping a List rather than a Dict, without subclassing?

"which shows up immediately as a type hinting problem" not really, since I don't use any type-checking software and it would show up immediately when I realise the return value doesn't make any sense

The second subclass's name seems to be the same as the first's; I assume that's a typo? Please edit the question to also let us know how you are using BasicOperationResult in the form of a [mre], since your problem isn't "immediately" obvious to us strangers.

this question really has nothing to do with dataclasses, the fact that your class definition uses the dataclasses.dataclass code generator isn't relevant.

As an aside, if you care about type hinting, then don't suse response: Any (which basically means "don't type check"), use response: str | List | Dict

Why not make OperationResult generic in response type? Show usage example with basic context, please, now it looks like just @dataclass class OperationResult(Generic[_T]): response: _T should work...

Subclass it.
As of now, the type-checker has no idea that code 500 will always have a str response, or that Operation1 should always return a dict response with code 200 or a failure. So you should make subclasses that make this easy to understand. Eg:
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List, Dict, ClassVar, Any, Literal, Final


@dataclass(
    frozen=True,
)
class OperationResult:
    status_code: int
    response: str | List | Dict
    id: int | None = None


class FailureOperationResult(OperationResult):
    status_code: Literal[500] = 500
    response: Literal["Failed"] = "Failed"
    id: int | None = None
    def __init__(self, id: int|None = None): 
        self.id = id

class DictOperationResult(OperationResult):
    status_code: Literal[200] = 200
    response: dict[str, Any] 
    id: int | None = None
    def __init__(self, response: dict[str, Any], id: int|None = None): 
        self.response = response
        self.id = id

def operation1(a, b) -> FailureOperationResult | DictOperationResult:
    # Do stuff
    try:
        res = a / b
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return FailureOperationResult()
    else:
        return DictOperationResult({"response": res})


# now this works
result1 = operation1(1, 2)

if result1.status_code == 200:
    print(result1.response["response"])

